# При помощи какого ПО можно провести нагрузочное тестирование?

Tags: java, производительность, jmeter

Есть маршрутизатор, через него подаются запросы, логика такая, что нужно передавать zip архив с выпиской и подписью, рестом, метод пост, подпись не проверяется, но ее присутствие нужно для корректного теста.
При помощи джметра не получается упаковывать архивы, так как параметризованная выписка сохраняется в unsi формате в zip архив, соответственно кириллица плывет, и перекодировать не удается никаким способом в ютф8(испробовал абсолютно все, все равно показывает анси, хотя она изначально была в ютф8.

При помощи какого бесплатного ПО можно провести тест, или каким способом через джметр можно параметризовывать выписку, сохранять ее в архив, чтобы в файле с выпиской было только параметризованное тело запроса в ютф8, без адреса и метода, чистый запрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю что такое `unsi` формат, но если вы упаковываете архив через [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) или через [JSR223 элемент и Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) - это **вы** выбираете в какой кодировке сохраняется файл

Если у вас "плывет" кириллица - почитайте документацию или покажите код, которым вы пытаетесь упаковать запрос. Вот пример который генерирует файл в UTF-8:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def destination = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File('request' + ${__Random(100000,200000,)} + '.zip')), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

destination.putNextEntry(new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(prev.getSampleLabel() + '.xml'))
destination << prev.getSamplerData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)


destination.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подпись тоже можно сгенерировать тем же Groovy, пример можно найти в статье [How to Handle Dynamic AWS SigV4 in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aws-sigv4) и/или на [Github](https://github.com/jinlo02/Jmeter_AWS_Signature)

Comment: а еще вопросик, как добавить уже имеющийся на пк файл в этот же зип архив? можно какой нибудь источник информации хотя бы, а то по джава урокам в джметре что то не наполняется архив, может в джметре по иному как то